# dpm_run_callback erros when suspend/resume

Tags: 14.04, kernel, suspend

Every time I suspend/resume my laptop, I get the following error messages

```
dpm_run_callback(): pnp_bus_resume+0x0/0xa0 returns -19
PM: Device 00:06 failed to resume: error -19
```

This errors are logged into the `kern.log` file, but I don't know to which device they refer and how to fix them.

Any idea?